# How to finish reading the input for a SPOJ program in Java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader, eof

I was doing a problem on SPOJ which gives in the input as a series of integers (link here: http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/) on successive lines. We're supposed to stop the input when we reach the end of line. I've searched for a way to do this but to no avail. Most people suggested BufferedReader's readLine method but that doesn't seem to work (or maybe I've implemented it incorrectly . , I've also tried Scanner's hasNextline() but that requires us to press an extra enter at the end, which is not possible for the online judge)
I'll be grateful if someone can help me out.

```
 String s = "";
 while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
       long n = Long.parseLong(s);
       System.out.println(n);
       //....do the working....
 }
```

Comment: Your code should work fine. The while will end when the the standard input is finished. The online judge should take care of that. When you are testing locally, you'll need to end the input when you're done typing. In eclipse this can be done with CTRL+Z.